Problem in installing Rstudio packages in macOS sonoma 14.1
I have Macbook pro m3 (macOS Sonoma 14.1). Since I installed R and Rstudio, I can't download a single package in Rstudio. My Rstudio version is R-4.4.2-arm64.pkg.
I used the terminal to download Homebrew and then the install the packages on Rstudio. Unfortunately, I couldn’t install the packages regardless trying for several times. Every time I try to install the packages, the following text is shown:
The downloaded binary packages are in
    /var/folders/gb/mkjjrcy57874jbgxp_6qmqrh0000gn/T//Rtmpin9Fzl/downloaded_packages
> library(codetools)
> install.packages("datasets.load", dependencies = FALSE)
trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/macosx/big-sur-arm64/contrib/4.4/datasets.load_2.3.0.tgz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 32456 bytes (31 KB)
==================================================
downloaded 31 KB


The downloaded binary packages are in
    /var/folders/gb/mkjjrcy57874jbgxp_6qmqrh0000gn/T//Rtmpin9Fzl/downloaded_packages

how to run and install them correctly?
